# I am getting following error in my c-sharp code. please give me idea how to fix it

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

**Getting Following Error in Polymorphism**

I'm getting this error in my C# Code as I'm New to C-Sharp, So I'm Struggling to Fix this One.

Here's the Error Am Getting:

[Error or Warning Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z9Ym.png)

Comment: You forgot to paste the error I'm afraid. Ah there we go.

Comment: You should `override` this method, and declare it as `virtual` in the base class (`Animal`?)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post the code and the error message as text, formatted appropriately. If a screen shot adds value then you can post it as well but NEVER instead. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need to use the `new` keyword if you want to replace the implementation from the parent class.

```
public new void animalSound()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It is a warning.
Using "new" keyword in method declaration as

`public new void animalSound()`

will silence the warning. But, it is better to understand what is going on.
Refer to this Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) to understand this warning as well as the difference between using "new" and "override" keywords in C# polymorphism.